# get a list of specific value from a list of dictionaries without using for loops or if conditions only if necessary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say I have a list of dictionaries.

```
listOfDict = [{"name": "Joel","Age": "10","Grade": "A"},{"name": "Adam","Age": "11","Grade": "B"},{"name": "Rachel","Age": "10","Grade": "B"}]
```

I want to get a list of names whose age is 10. So output would look like this.

```
listOfNames = ["Joel", "Rachel"]
```

Is there a way to do this without using for loops or if conditions. I tried to use Lambda function but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this without using for loops or if conditions

## No, there isn't!

Use a loop. It's unavoidable at *some* level. Using a list comprehension:

```
res = [d['name'] for d in listOfDict if d['Age'] == '10']
```

Answer (score 1):

This works.

**Using lambda:**

```
result = list(map(lambda x: x['name'] if x['Age'] == "10" else None, listOfDict ))
result = [x for x in result if x is not None]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

No `for` loops or `if` conditions using [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(listOfDict)
result=df[df['Age']=='10']['name'].tolist()
```

OUTPUT

```
['Joel', 'Rachel']
```

Comment: Chained indexing is explicitly discouraged in the docs, use `df.loc[df['Age'] == '10', 'name']].tolist()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a way** to use lambda functions, along with `map` and `filter` to get your desired result without using neither `for` loop or `if` condition, but the code will be a bit difficult to read:

```
listOfDict = [{"name": "Joel","Age": "10","Grade": "A"},{"name": "Adam","Age": "11","Grade": "B"},{"name": "Rachel","Age": "10","Grade": "B"}]

listOfNames = list(map(lambda elem: elem['name'], list(filter(lambda elem: elem['Age']=="10",listOfDict))))

print(listOfNames)
```

Result:

```
['Joel', 'Rachel']
```

Comment: Not only difficult to read, but *also* less efficient. We should note getting rid of `for` / `if` statements doesn't necessarily lead to optimized code.

Comment: @jpp I totally agree with you, but the OP's question was to find a way to get the desired result without using `for` loop or `if` conditions.